# column width in cxDBTreeList

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I need to know the width of the column in cxdbtreelist,for example:
columntautowidth = true.
cxdbtreelist.align = altop.

```
procedure Tform1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  lable1.Caption := IntToStr(cxDBTreeList1.Columns[0].Width);
 end;
```

but,after resize form, column size does not change.
Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that the value shown by "lable1.Caption" does not change, or that the on-screen width of Columns[0] does not change?

Comment: the value shown by "lable1.Caption" does not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I can reproduce that.

The cause is simple: I think you'll find that the OLH says that the column's Width is the value set in the designer.  The column's DisplayWidth is the property which reflects its current, on-screen width. Try this:

```
procedure TForm1.ShowColWidth(ColNo : Integer);
begin
  Caption := IntToStr(cxDBTreeList1.Columns[ColNo].Width) + '/' +  IntToStr(cxDBTreeList1.Columns[ColNo].DisplayWidth); 
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowColWidth(0);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowColWidth(0);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowColWidth(0);
end;
```

You should find that the *Width* property updates at run-time to reflect any changes caused by changing the width of the column's header.